# Conditionally apply CSS classes in React

Tags: reactjs

I know this has been answered but I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code here. I'm trying to add a class based of the conditional field.

React Code:

```
<div className="boards {task.IsClosed !== 0 ? 'complete' : ''}">
  <p>{task.TaskName}</p>
  <div>{task.IsClosed !== 0 ? <div>Completed</div> : null}</div>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="boards {task.IsClosed !== 0 ? 'complete' : ''}">
  <p>Task 2</p>
  <div><div>Completed</div></div>
</div>
```

I want the output to be `<div class="boards complete">`

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div className=`boards ${task.IsClosed !== 0 ? 'complete' : ''}`>
  <p>{task.TaskName}</p>
  <div>{task.IsClosed !== 0 ? <div>Completed</div> : null}</div>
</div>
```

I think you want this^^^

for string interpolation in javascript the ` character must be used for quotes and the expression being interpolated must be within ${}

...
or you can make a variable to store the class i.e.

```html
let className = task.IsClosed !== 0 ? 'complete' : '';
...
...
<div className={className}>
  <p>{task.TaskName}</p>
  <div>{task.IsClosed !== 0 ? <div>Completed</div> : null}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it resolve with this code: className={`boards__body${task.IsClosed !== 0 ? ` complete` : ''}`}